Not handling JSON-conversion of IList<string> into database
I'm using Linq2DB and the EF Core plugin for it. However, I noticed when trying to implement bulk-insert that some columns that otherwise work in EF Core fail with the following exception:

The given value 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]' of type List1 from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar for Column 14 [OrderNumbers].

The class which contains the property in question is set up like this:
public IList<string> OrderNumbers { get; set; } = new List<string>();

While the column in the SQL Server database is defined as nvarchar(max).
The class which configures the table for this class is setup like this:
builder.Property(x => x.OrderNumbers)
       .HasColumnOrder(15);

This is using a fairly-recent feature implemented in EF Core 7 or 8 which allows for automatically converting a list of primitives to a JSON column in the database.
I've tried calling this in my unit test which is testing the bulk-insert functionality but it's a no-go so far:
MappingSchema.Default.SetConverter<List<string>, object>(list => JsonSerializer.Serialize(list));
MappingSchema.Default.SetConverter<List<string>, SqlString>(list => JsonSerializer.Serialize(list));
MappingSchema.Default.SetConverter<List<string>, string>(list => JsonSerializer.Serialize(list));
MappingSchema.Default.SetConverter<IList<string>, object>(list => JsonSerializer.Serialize(list));
MappingSchema.Default.SetConverter<IList<string>, SqlString>(list => JsonSerializer.Serialize(list));
MappingSchema.Default.SetConverter<IList<string>, string>(list => JsonSerializer.Serialize(list));

Is MappingSchema.Default.SetConverter an appropriate method to convert lists of strings to a nvarchar? Has anyone done something similar?

Out of curiosity why are you storing multiple IDs in a single column anyway, shouldn't this be normalized out to a separate table eg CustomerOrder?

linq2db should support EF Core's HasConversion, why do not use it?

@Charlieface yes, that's certainly an option but this field (and some others like it) aren't core enough to the business logic to warrant splitting into their own table and the additional overhead that goes with it. JSON columns make for a convient middle ground that keeps the schema simple.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv actually, originally I did have a HasConversion definition in the configuration of the table for converting to and from JSON. But when I moved to EFCore8, I had to remove it because it wasn't playing nice with its built-in logic. It's been working without the manual conversion since. But I'm trying to implement a bulk-insert solution and linq2db isn't picking up on the conversion. Also, linq2db is just for this small function so I don't want to change my configs much just to make l2db work

It is bad to set such conversion for everything. linq2db also has HasConversion and you can specify which property to convert.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv correct, setting a global conversion isn't ideal. I don't see any Linq2Db documentation on where and how that functionality is set. Do you have a link or example?

Check this test

"a convient middle ground that keeps the schema simple" I don't know, I find a dynamic JSON column to be more complex if anything.

@Charlieface fair enough. I tend to take the same position as Shay Rojansky on the matter: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29427#issuecomment-1354907412

@Killnine you misunderstand what this talks about. Roj is the maintainer of NpgSQL and PostgreSQL has native support for arrays. A bunch of strings is one thing. Data that can be queried, indexed and combined is a very different thing. And even in databases that do support indexing and querying inside JSON, you're forced to query the data in a very specific way - from parent to child. That was the disadvantage of document/hierarchical and network/graph databases that lead to the creation of the relational model.

@Charlieface for this JSON column these are random user-input strings. These aren't FKs to other tables...

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I created a gist here with how I changed the DbContext registration to try and register the mapping behavior: https://gist.github.com/killnine/419624e4c0ef5a328152c0be0fad6793 But it still errors with the same message. I can see it executing when the test case executes, so perhaps syntax for registration isn't correct?

Well, I see. I forgot that we override MappingSchema behaviour in EF Core extension. It will not work. Please start dicussion in linq2db repository.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv my gist actually DID work, I just realized that I have two properties that were IList=>nvarchar and I setup only one of them.
I'm going to submit as a solution.

I was able to get my issue resolved by registering the different initializations and mappings in my service registration class:
public static IServiceCollection AddSqlServerServices(
          this IServiceCollection services,
          IConfiguration configuration)
      {
          LinqToDBForEFTools.Initialize();

          services.AddDbContextFactory<ExampleDbContext>(
              opt =>
              {
                  opt.UseSqlServer(
                      configuration.GetConnectionString("ExampleAppDb"));
                  opt.UseLinqToDB(builder =>
                  {
                      var mappingSchema = new MappingSchema();
                      var mapBuilder = new FluentMappingBuilder(mappingSchema);                                            mapBuilder.Entity<Bill>()
                          .Property(b => b.CustomerOrderNumbers)
                          .HasConversion(
                              list => JsonSerializer.Serialize(list, JsonSerializerOptions.Default),
                              s => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IList<string>>(s, JsonSerializerOptions.Default) ?? new List<string>())
                          .Build();
                      builder.AddMappingSchema(mappingSchema);
                  });
              },
              ServiceLifetime.Transient);

          // ... snip ...

          return services;
      }


LinqToDBForEFTools.Initialize();: This sets things up so I can use DbContext normally
UseLinqToDB: This allows me to customize the schema to include the custom property I needed it to treat differently.

Note: Since my unit tests do not run service registration classes, I would probably abstract this Linq2Db stuff to its own class and call it from both the unit test class and in this service registration class. That way, if mappings needed to change, I would only need to do in one place.
